# Google Cloud Text-To-Speech Character counts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I am using Google Cloud TTS for a personal project and though there is almost negligible chance that it will hit 1M characters / month but I would like to know is there any way to create an alert when certain limit is reached? Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So,

I came across the same problem recently where I needed to know the exact number of characters used.

Turn out in the billing report if you group by SKU in the filters on the right side it shows the exact number of characters used for the range you set, split of by normal and wavenet voices.

[image]

Though that data only gets updated once a day apparently.

Not sure if you can check the limit automatically maybe with https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list
or something.

Answer (score 1):

In the console you can see the text to speech quota per day:
Standard Edition characters count of text-to-speech queries per day

I recommend to keep and save the count.

To can get to the quotas:
IAM & Admin > Quotas
and the look for test to speech

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. It shows the message that no data is available for the selected time frame even if I select 30 days period which is the maximum I can select there. The API is certainly sending the characters to generate speech and I can see the traffic from Text-To-Speech metrics.

Comment: An update: GGC acknowledged that something could be wrong with my account and they will investigate and update.

Comment: @DLB555, have you figured this out in the end? I don't see anything either.

Comment: @nphx , I did not hear back from the support, but I think they gave me an alternative way to see the report. I do not remember what it was, I'd recommending contacting their support if it is still a problem.